# Redirect Category URL to Contacts Page In Magento

Tags: magento, url

I have a `category` named `About Us`. Which is in top navigation. So i want when user click on the `About Us`. Its redirect to the Magento default `contacts` page.
I know `Magento` `URL` rewriting. and i have changed some category urls to CMS pages. But for contacts, its not working.

Comment: Please show what you changed/did

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is the most intuitive way to add CMS pages to your navigation, but here is a possible solution.

You can display the contacts form as the content for your category page by using the relevant parts of your theme's contact.xml as a Custom Layout Update.

For the category, on the Display Settings tab set Display Mode to "Static Block Only". No need to select a CMS block.

Next, on the category's Custom Design tab, copy the "content" reference from contacts.xml into the Custom Layout Update field. Note that you must also set formAction, as this is not done on contacts.xml

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml">
        <action method="setFormAction"><formAction>contacts/index/post</formAction></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

You may have to experiment with getting the correct formAction value.

Once set up, the form will display when your category page is viewed.

Please note that when the user fills out and submits the form, they will be directed to the "real" contact page. If this is a problem, you will have to override the contact controller to direct appropriately.